# Issue with steghide/StegCracker tool

Tags: kali-linux-tools

I'm trying to use StegCracker for a school assignment, however I got a `/bin/stegcracker: line 1: 404:: command not found` error message.

I tried to install and run StegCracker with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install steghide -y
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Paradoxis/StegCracker/master/stegcracker > /bin/stegcracker
chmod +x /bin/stegcracker
stegcracker 000001.jpg passwordlist.txt
```

Comment: The problem is that https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Paradoxis/StegCracker/master/stegcracker is no valid link but returns a 404 error (Not Found) if you visit it in the browser. Have a look at the repository's readme at https://github.com/Paradoxis/StegCracker/ for the real installation instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Stegseek](https://github.com/RickdeJager/stegseek) is a lightning fast steghide cracker that can be used to extract hidden data from files. It is built as a fork of the original steghide project and, as a result, it is thousands of times faster than other crackers and can run through the entirety of rockyou.txt (a well-known password list with over 14 million passwords) in under 2 seconds.

---

[StegCracker](https://github.com/Paradoxis/StegCracker) is a steganography brute force utility to uncover hidden data inside files.

1. StegCracker requires Python 3.6 or later and the steghide binary to be installed. Python 3.6 or later is installed by default in Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

   ```
    sudo apt install steghide -y
   ```
2. To install the program, run the following command:

   ```
    python3 -m pip install --user stegcracker
   ```
3. To update the program, simply pass `-U` to the installation command.

   ```
    python3 -m pip install --user stegcracker -U --force-reinstall
   ```

Comment: I would recommend against `sudo pip3`. It's usually better to install python packages for your user only and by calling `pip` as a module instead of the executable directly: `python3 -m pip install --user stegcracker`.

Comment: Nowadays I would use StegSeek you can find it here: https://github.com/RickdeJager/stegseek it's also stated in StegCracker:
`StegCracker has been retired following the release of StegSeek, which 
will blast through the rockyou.txt wordlist within 1.9 second as opposed 
to StegCracker which takes ~5 hours.`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply (I only found this after Googling my own project) but as @ByteCommander and @karel stated, the real instructions are on the [GitHub repo itself](https://github.com/Paradoxis/StegCracker/) and should be more future-proof, I recommend you check that out instead for the most up-to-date documentation, and if you have issues installing stuff or find bugs, use that bug tracker instead. I reply to all issues.

#### Why did I get a 404 error?

The reason you get a 404 is due to the fact that 'stegcracker' is now a directory containing Python source code, which you obviously can't download with one http request so GitHub returns a 404 html page instead which bash tried to run as code and failed miserably to.

#### Why did you change it?

I had to rewrite the entire codebase as the project was initially written as a bash script for myself in the 1.0 version and was terribly slow (full details are in [this issue](https://github.com/Paradoxis/StegCracker/issues/6) and [this blog post](https://blog.paradoxis.nl/stegcracker-2-released-f03771ba855b)). TL;DR, small hobby project got out of hand, it had no threading and every password attempt had to wait for steghide to test if it worked and wait for the terminal to output the current attempt, rewrite was 2960% faster (a lot).

---

Regarding the school assignment though, what kind of assignment did you get? 
Never knew my projects got used in schools, quite cool to see :)